# Pass list of custom types in Silverlight Ria services

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, ria

i have to read csv file.
from csv file, i have to create a List list
And then return it to the calling method.

do you recommend any other alternative?  also CustomClass has a property List.  It's always null on the silverlight side.  Can you tell me what the solution is?

Comment: Hand us over your project and we will do everything for ya. from A to Z! or else provide us with some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [Include] and [Associate] attributes for properties of the class.

Also to read data, we can return an IEnumerable type e.g. list, ilist from our ria service to the silverlight application